# How to completely disable backupd-helper?

Tags: backup

I am using `macOS High Sierra 10.13.5`, and with `iCloud` enabled.

I tried to kill `backupd-helper` many times, and I didn't have Time machine running, but it keeps use my disk IO:

[image]

Even after I kill the process, it will automatically start again. How can I completely disable it? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try navigating to '/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.backupd-helper.plist' and changing 'RunAtLoad' to NO. I haven't tested this out, but I suspect it would work.

This (editing the plist) can also be done from the command line, but I won't get into that here.